# Extracting information using ElementTree

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, elementtree

XML is https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=London,us&mode=xml&appid=439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02
I would like to extract to the console only latitude and longitude, date, hour, altitude, rainfall, pressure, wind spead, wind direction so that the final result looks like this (first three things normally(which is hourly forecast), the rest in the table):

```
    City: London
    
    Latitude,longitude: 51.509865/-0.118092
    
    Altitude: 11

 From 2017-03-03T21:00:00 to: 2017-03-04T00:00:00
    **Name**           **Value**
    Rainfall:      0, 
    Pressure:      1012.92
    Wind spead     4.26
    wind direction West-northwest

From 2017-03-03T21:00:00 to: 2017-03-04T00:00:00
  **Name**           **Value**
    Rainfall:        0, 
    Pressure:        1012.92
    Wind spead       4.26
    wind direction   West-northwest
    
From...
.
.
.
e.t.c.
```

Until now, only I wrote this:

**Script:**

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import requests

def get_forecast_data(api_url):

    call = requests.get(api_url)
    call.raise_for_status()

    tree = ET.fromstring(call.text)
    for child in tree:
        print(child.tag, child.attrib)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    forecast_url = str(r'https://samples.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=London,us&mode=xml&appid=439d4b804bc8187953eb36d2a8c26a02')
    print(get_forecast_data(forecast_url))
```

And I'm stuck with it, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to approach it is, I believe, to do it this way:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from lxml import etree

url = "https://www.yr.no/place/United_States/Massachusetts/Boston/forecast_hour_by_hour.xml"
req = requests.get(url) #use requests to get the data

doc = etree.XML(req.content) #since the data is in xml format, use an xml parser

#get location data using xpath:

loc = doc.xpath('//location/name/text()')[0]
lat = doc.xpath('//location/@latitude')[0]
lon = doc.xpath('//location/@longitude')[0]
alt = doc.xpath('//location/@altitude')[0]

rows = [] #initialize a list to collect the tabular data:

for dat in doc.xpath('//tabular'):
    hours = dat.xpath('./time')
    sky = dat.xpath('.//symbol')
    tmpr = dat.xpath('.//temperature')
    for t,s,tm in zip(hours,sky,tmpr):        
        rows.extend([(t.xpath('./@from')[0],t.xpath('./@to')[0],s.xpath('./@name')[0],tm.xpath('./@value')[0])])
#now prepare your dataframe:
columns = ['From','To','Sky','Temperature'] #set the column headers
print('Location: ',loc)
print('Longitude: ',lon)
print('Latitude: ',lat)
print('Altitude: ',alt)
#create the dataframe
pd.DataFrame(rows,columns=columns)
```

Output:

```
Location:  Boston
Longitude:  -71.05977
Latitude:  42.35843
Altitude:  14
    From                    To                      Sky       Temperature
0   2020-06-20T08:00:00     2020-06-20T09:00:00     Clear sky   24
1   2020-06-20T09:00:00     2020-06-20T10:00:00     Partly cloudy   27
2   2020-06-20T10:00:00     2020-06-20T11:00:00     Clear sky   29
```

etc.

Obviously, you can modify it to change display values, formatting, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Below

```
import requests
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

r = requests.get('https://www.yr.no/place/United_States/Massachusetts/Boston/forecast_hour_by_hour.xml')
if r.status_code == 200:
    root = ET.fromstring(r.text)
    loc = root.find('./location')
    print('Location: {}'.format(loc.find('./name').text))
    inner_loc = loc.find('./location')
    print('Longitude: {}'.format(inner_loc.attrib['longitude']))
    print('Latitude: {}'.format(inner_loc.attrib['latitude']))
    print('Altitude: {}'.format(inner_loc.attrib['altitude']))
    print()

    entries = root.findall('.//time')
    for e in entries:
      print('From: {} to: {}'.format(e.attrib['from'],e.attrib['to']))
      p = e.find('./precipitation')
      t = e.find('./temperature')
      c = e.find('./symbol')
      print('Cloudiness: {}, precipitation: {} , Temperature: {}'.format(c.attrib['name'],p.attrib['value'],t.attrib['value']))
      print()
 
else:
    print('Failed to read xml. status code: {}'.format(r.status_code))
```

Comment: It is the date format. Feel free to vote up if my answer solved your issue.